# practical exam ATCL ABRSM Diploma

Tags: piano, exam-grades, abrsm, exam

I've finished the Performance certificate from Trinity College London, and now I would like to continue with the ATCL Diploma from ABRSM. Does it include any theory parts that I need to pass before I take the exam?

Comment: Do you want to do a teacher diploma or performance?

Answer (score 1):

The diploma syllabus gives a full list of requirements and the equivalent qualifications from other boards. 
The DipABRSM requires grade 8 practical, which requires grade 5 theory.  Grades from other boards are accepted but it also notes that grade 5 theory is required in addition, though from any board. All the higher diplomas require lower ones, so eventually require theory.

You can also substitute qualifications from music colleges;these generally have some theory component as well.

The syllabus is [here](http://gb.abrsm.org/en/our-exams/diplomas/music-performance/#) and the information is under 'prerequisites and substitutes' (about page 20)

Answer (score 0):

With ABRSM, to take any grade higher than V in practical, one must pass grade V theory. Best bet is to look on the ABRSM site for FAQs, or to find a phone number to call - they are very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

ABRSM also has its own forums where you can get additional information.

[LINK](http://www.abrsm.org/forum/index.php?s=ad863d8eb070eaceb52c7ecf4b9d4d1e&act=idx)